# Change order custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, order, slug

I've created a custom taxonomy **BH Job Regions** . Now I would like to *change the order of the terms* in my taxonomy list.

Is there a plugin or so that I can do this in my backend? Drag the terms in order? I've found the plugin [Category Order and Taxonomy Terms Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/). But that only works with standard taxonomy lists, not with my custom created taxonomy list.

I've also tried to set the slug and order them by slug but that didn't work. This is the case:

Term with Name: Brussel and slug: aa
Term with Name: Antwerp and slug: bb
Term with Name: Vlaams-Brabant and slug: cc
Term with Name: West-Vlaanderen and slug: dd

But my select list shows this:

```
<select name="JOBREGION" id="JOBREGION">
   <option value="Brussel">Brussel</option>
   <option value="Vlaams-Brabant">Vlaams-Brabant</option>
   <option value="Antwerpen">Antwerpen</option>
   <option value="West-Vlaanderen">West-Vlaanderen</option>
</select>
```

(Slug names a,b and c already occupied so I use double)

So the second and third options should switch places... . What could be the problem here?

**UPDATE:**

This is how I create my taxonomy terms:

```
/**
 * Job Regions Taxonomy
 */
$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Job Regions', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Job Region', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Job Regions' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Job Regions' ),
    'parent_item'       => null,
    'parent_item_colon' => null,
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Job Region' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Job Region' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Job Region' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Job Region' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'BH Job Regions' ),
);

$args = array(
    'hierarchical'      => false,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'job_regions' ),
);

register_taxonomy( 'job_regions', array( 'job_listing' ), $args );
```

https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/

Comment: that plugin claimed that it worked for Categories and all custom taxonomies terms.

Comment: I don't have the paying version, could be the problem?

Comment: I have not tried it. Have you tried? what have you found out? it only works for standard categories?

Comment: Yes, when I go the ordering page I only see the standard and not my custom taxonomy lists.

Comment: can you show your code on how you added the custom taxonomy?

Comment: updated my topic